# Mostrar/Ocultar Div mediante un bucle para distintos elementos Javascript / JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, div

muchas gracias por leer esta publicación, he tenido un pequeño inconveniente en el uso de javascript. Lo que sucede es que quiero hacer un sitio de preguntas frecuentes, donde inicialmente solo aparecerá la pregunta y por medio de CSS las respuestas estarán ocultas, al momento de hacer clic sobre la pregunta quiero que aparezca con un slide la respuesta.

Este es el código:

```
<!--Contenedor de Pregunta-->
<div class="questions">
    <div id="q-1" class="question">
        <!--Pregunta 1-->
    </div>
    <div id="a-1" class="answer">
        <!--Respuesta 1-->
    </div>
</div>
<!--Contenedor de Pregunta-->
<div class="questions">
    <div id="q-2" class="question">
        <!--Pregunta 1-->
    </div>
    <div id="a-2" class="answer">
        <!--Respuesta 1-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Si bien puedo meter manualmente cada numero de pregunta y respuesta como a continuación:

```
$('#q-1').click(function(){
        $('#a-1').slideToggle();
 }); 
$('#q-2').click(function(){
        $('#a-2').slideToggle();
});
```

Esto no representa ningún problema cuando se trata de una cantidad de preguntas pequeña, sin embargo si requiero introducir más preguntas, ¿Cómo puedo reescribir el código de javascript por medio de un bucle para que automáticamente pueda mostrar la respuesta "#a-n" a una pregunta con un id de valor cualquiera "#q-n"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Viendo tu código creo que puedes hacer algo como:

```
$('.question').click(function () {
     $(this).next('.answer').slideToggle();
});
```